# Setting Text of Label To Data Retrieved From SQL Database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webforms, label

I am building a website in ASP.NET Web Forms with a SQL Database. The database contains a table with 571 entry's of data. My problem occurs when outputting the data to the labels. Screenshots below.

**Database Example**

[image]

**Source Code**

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built FROM Houses", connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                                lblId.Text = reader[0].ToString();
                                lblName.Text = reader[1].ToString();
                                lblTown.Text = reader[2].ToString();
                                lblNear.Text = reader[3].ToString();
                                lblStatus.Text = reader[4].ToString();
                                lblBuilt.Text = reader[5].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Expected Output**

[image]

**Actual Output**

[image]

My question is why is it outputting a random house instead of starting at the first one?

Comment: Without any condition u didn't get any proper value for output.based on your requirement just use where,top,order by ,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't instructed it on which ordering it should use:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built FROM Houses ORDER BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no `WHERE` clause to all rows are returned.  Your code will assign the label text to the last row returned, which could be any row by happenstance because you have no ORDER by clause.

It seems you have want to display multiple houses.  That will require a separate set of labels for each house.  Only one is apparent in your code.

Comment: Is there a way of outputting all 571 entry's without repeating code like the same way a master page is used to give a consistent design

Comment: @ProDiablo, yes but you should ask a new question since you already closed this one.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use any condtion in ur sql query.

```
SELECT Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built FROM Houses order by Id
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 5 Id, Name, Townland, Near, Status, Built  FROM Houses ;--It select only first 5 values in the table
```